# Error binding parameter 2 - probably unsupported type

Tags: django

The code below is from `views.py`

```
def register(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
    form = RegisterForm (request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        success = True
        first_name = form.cleaned_data[ 'first_name']
        last_name = form.cleaned_data[ 'last_name']
        username  = form.cleaned_data[ 'username' ]
        password = form.cleaned_data[ 'password']
        confirm_password = form.cleaned_data[ 'confirm_password']
        address  = form.cleaned_data[ 'address' ]
        form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/success/")
    else:
        form=RegisterForm()
    return render_to_response('homepage/register.html',
        {'form':form,},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Below the error traceback:

```
  Traceback:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in 
  get_response 
  92. response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)   
  File "/root/Desktop/blog/blog/../blog/apps/homepage/views.py" in register
  99. form.save()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/forms/models.py" in save
  407. fail_message, commit, exclude=self._meta.exclude)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/forms/models.py" in save_instance
  78.         instance.save()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save
  410.         self.save_base(force_insert=force_insert, force_update=force_update)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save_base
  495.                     result = manager._insert(values, return_id=update_pk)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in _insert
  177.         return insert_query(self.model, values, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in          
  insert_query
  1087.     return query.execute_sql(return_id)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/subqueries.py" in 
  execute_sql
  320.         cursor = super(InsertQuery, self).execute_sql(None)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in 
  execute_sql
  2369.         cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py" in execute
  19.             return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py" in 
  execute
  193.         return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
  Exception Type: InterfaceError at /register/
  Exception Value: Error binding parameter 2 - probably unsupported type.
```

What throws  Error binding parameter 2 - probably unsupported type. in a code?

I'm new I don't know how to solve this Exception? Thanks.

Comment: Don't just cut out the actual useful error messages and say "etc etc". They're there for a reason. Post them.

Comment: Problem is clearly not in views.py (except creating a bunch of variables and not using them), I assume that it's in overloaded form.save() method or in model...

Comment: I think we need to have a look at the RegisterForm to track this down.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question, but I had an issue similar to this and would like to share my finding.

**My solution**: I was using the configuration below in my `settings/dev.py`

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': ':memory:',
    }
}
```

And in my model I had:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    parameter0 = django.contrib.postgres.fields.JSONField()
```

Then, when Django tried to insert the `parameter0` with `MyModel(parameter0=some_value).save()`, it was not supported by the database.

Comment: Thanks for posting this, I suspect I have the same issue. How did you end up editing the database to allow the JSONField?

Comment: I was using an SQLite3 database in the test environment but a Postgresql in production, so I ended up following [10th rule of Twelve-Factor App](https://12factor.net/dev-prod-parity) and used the same database (Postgresql) in both environments.

However, if you want to use just SQLite with the JSONField, I believe a solution like [this](https://github.com/dmkoch/django-jsonfield) could be useful.